# I don't understand the use of ようなこと in this context

Tags: grammar

recently I came across the following sentence:

アタシ。。。お前らを応援するようなこと言ってたのに。。。

I'm really confused by the use of ような in this context. Hope someone could help me understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: What's your interpretation so far of the phrase?

Comment: Well, the part up until ような is pretty straightforward. Given the のに at the end, it seems the phrase could mean something along the lines of "Even though I said I was rooting for you/cheering you on...".

My Japanese knowledge is still pretty bare-boned though, so I'm a bit afraid of jumping to conclusions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it means 'like' or 'that kind of'.

You can think that:

[Aのようなこと] means'something like, similar to or the same as A'.

So I would agree with your interpretation. Maybe the speaker hadnt exactly said 'I support you guys', but they said something along those lines, in that vein.